# Import CSV with long numbers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I am going to keep this question simple.

I am trying to import a CSV file into my application.
The file has long numbers in it such as :"9405510200830754182150"

but when the file is imported the data looks like this: "9.40551e+21"

does anyone know how to get around this?

Here is the code I am using

```
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
   puts "row: #{row.inspect}"
end
```

---

### UPDATE

Thank you for the comments, I am not sure why CSV is converting that number into a float i need to keep it as a string.

I should clarify that I am using Rails 3.2.18 for this project

If you want to reproduce my code:

1.create CSV with 9405510200830754182150 in it

2.run this code to terminal:

```
file = File.join(Rails.root, 'tracking.csv')
CSV.foreach(file, headers: true) do |row|
   puts "row: #{row.inspect}"
end
```

I need to be able to keep "9405510200830754182150" is a string since this is a tracking number of an order and needs to be stored in the database

Comment: `9.40551e+21` looks correct to me, are you concerned it is actually truncating your value?  I think you're just being spooked by how it looks when printed by default.

Comment: When I use that code, everything comes out of the CSV as strings. What are you doing to produce that floating point value?

Comment: That code doesn't produce the results you're claiming. We need enough code and data to replicate the problem or everything's guesswork.

Comment: But who is converting that string to a float? What exactly does that `puts "row: #{row.inspect}"` produce on the standard output for you?

Comment: it turns out the CSV file being exported would convert them values into a float, the only way to solve this would be to use the "Import" wizard in excel to mark the column as "text"..

However i wonder if there is a way to this without going through that extra process?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `"9.40551e+21"` is not a visual approximation? Try this:

```
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
  puts row['my_numeric_header']
end
```

Comment: 9.40551e+21 is a representation of a floating point value, `9405510200830754182150` should end up as a Bignum.

Comment: You're right, it is a float; I thought it could be some kind of BigNum approximation

Comment: [`Bignum#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Bignum.html#method-i-to_s) gives you the whole thing. And when I run the OP's code, I get strings out of the CSV so there's a mystery `to_f` call somewhere that we're not being shown.

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to treat everything in a CSV file as a string by default. You could try the converters: numeric option

```
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, converters: :numeric) do |row|
  puts "row: #{row.inspect}"
end
```

Which will interpret numbers into the appropriate types. Otherwise you might have to debug the CSV module code to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The `:float` converter converted your number to a `Float` for you.  Unfortunately Float cannot hold such a large number, see comments...

```
[14] pry(main)> val = CSV::Converters[:float].('9405510200830754182150')
=> 9.405510200830755e+21
[15] pry(main)> val.class
=> Float
[16] pry(main)> "%d" % val
=> "9405510200830754553856"
[17] pry(main)> "%f" % val
=> "9405510200830754553856.000000"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the data is not lost"? `'9405510200830754182150'` becoming `'9405510200830754553856'` looks like data loss to me. `9405510200830754553856` has too many digits to fit in a Float without loss of precision. `CSV::Converters[:integer]`, OTOH, does The Right Thing (i.e. uses Bignum instead of Fixnum or Float).

Comment: Oops!  I only glanced at the first 10 or so digits and it looked good.  Didn't even think about floating point precision issues...  That sucks!  Good catch.

Comment: Someone is doing a `to_f` call somewhere that they're not showing us. The code in the question is not the real code.